# Smarty variables concatenation

Tags: php, smarty

I have something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="activ">
 {if {$smarty.session.admin['access']['pages:list:activ']} == '1'}
   <option value="1">{#L_YES#}</option>
   <option value="0">{#L_NO#}</option>
 {else}
   <option value="0">{#L_NO#}</option>
 {/if}
</select>
```

I need to change `['pages:list:activ']` to `['{$smarty.get.module}:list:activ']`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options here..

For one, PHP will not parse variables when you are using single quotes.

So

```
$a = 'string';
echo '$test with something';
```

Will output:

```
$test with something
```

But if you use:

```
$a = 'string';
echo "$test with something";
```

or

```
echo "{$test} with something";
```

It will output:

```
string with something
```

But for Smarty this will not work if you use `.` or `->` in the name, because you will have to use backticks around the variable, like this (note the double quotes around it):

```
{if {$smarty.session.admin['access']["`$smarty.get.module`:list:activ"]} == '1'}
```

For more info see: [Smarty Embedding Vars in Double Quotes](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl)

---

You can also use cat modifier and assign the concatenated value to a var:

```
{assign var = "moduleList" value = $smarty.get.module|cat:":list:activ"}
{if {$smarty.session.admin['access'][$moduleList]} == '1'}
```